# Spring Tool Suite: Deployment Assembly option in Properties

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I'm trying to run example of web-app with use of Spring MVC on Spring tool Suite 3.3. I found someone who explains step by step how to do it, but at some point he wrote:

> b) Right click on spitter-web project, select Properties>Deployment
>   Assembly
>   -Add... Folder "/src/main/webapp", Deploy Path is /

Unfortunately there isn't `Properties>Deployment Assembly` option in my STS - he used 2.8.1 version. Where I can find that option, or it was renamed ?

Answer (score 0):

Properties is usually at the bottom of the drop down list when right clicking a project.
Alternatively, right click project, then go "build path" -> "configure build path". A new menu will come up, and if you look on the left hand side, you should see deployment assembly there.